# Change Password using API Laravel

Tags: laravel, postman

I was trying to do the change password using API Laravel, but it didn't work. I'm new to API Laravel.

Any suggestion to solve my problem?

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function store(ChangePasswordValidation $request)
{
    if(Auth::check($data['current_password'], $user->password))
    {
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->update(["password"=> bcrypt($request->password)]);
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('newToken')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], 200);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
    }
}
```

The result shown in Postman is:

```json
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

Comment: Where did you write your route in web.php or api.php ?

Comment: in api.php -> Route::post('/change-password', 'Auth\ChangePasswordController@store');

Answer (score 0):

You need to use guard as you are using API
so change

```
Auth::user()
```

To

```
Auth::user('api')
```

also

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```

To

```
$this->middleware('auth:api');
```

Comment: It still didn't work. It shows the same result { "message": "Unauthenticated." } when I test it using Postman

Comment: are you sending bearer token in header in your request?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question but I think is a no. sorry. I'm very new to API.

Comment: make sure you are not using any auth middleware for route or controller

Answer (score 0):

Edit this line

```
if(Auth::check($data['current_password'], $user->password))
```

Into

```
if(Auth::check($request['current_password'], $user->password))
```

Answer (score -1):

`Auth::check` usage means: The Auth::check method is typically used to check if the user is currently logged in. To check if the provided current password matches the user's actual password, you should use the Hash::check method.

`createToken` method: The createToken method is typically used on an instance of the User model, not on the password itself. In your case, you are trying to use it on the updated user model

```
public function store(ChangePasswordValidation $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user(); // Get the authenticated user

    // Check if the provided current password matches the user's actual password
    if(Hash::check($request->current_password, $user->password))
    {
        // Update the user's password
        $user->update(["password" => bcrypt($request->password)]);

        // Create a new token for the user
        $token = $user->createToken('newToken')->accessToken;

        // Return a success response
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'token' => $token], 200);
    }
    else
    {
        // Return an unauthorized error response
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorised'], 401); 
    }
}
```

I have used `Auth::user()` to get the authenticated user.

and also replaced `Auth::check` with `Hash::check` to compare the current password with the user's actual password.

I've corrected the usage of the createToken method to be used on the user instance.